# Automatically Show Touch Keyboard in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

i want to show automatically the Touch Keyboard in MS access when i click on a textbox, wondering why this is not working, is there maybe some property? I also wondering why this is not showing up automatically if i click in a excel cell...
 This Touch Keyboard:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ACCESS VBA` :

You have to write two lines of VB code

```
Call Shell("osk.exe", 1)
MyControl.SetFocus
```

or something like that, where my control is the name of the testbox, which should be activated.

Try this `WINDOWS 7`:

1. Start => Control Panel => Ease of access => Ease of Access Center

Under Explore all settings, select Use the computer without a mouse or keyboard.

Ease of Access Center

2. Under Type using a pointing device, select Use On-screen Keyboard. Click Apply, then OK

Use On-screen Keyboard

3. Select Change Administrative settings from the column on the left.

Change Administrative settings
Select Apply all settings to the logon desktop. Click Apply, then OK.

Try this `WINDOWS 10`

Windows 10 does a fairly good job producing the onscreen keyboard when needed, particularly when you've switched to tablet mode. However, getting the onscreen keyboard to pop-up automatically consistently when in desktop mode is difficult.

The keyboard icon in the Windows 10 System Tray helps. You can tap or click this to expose the onscreen keyboard.

But, you can also improve how the onscreen keyboard reacts through the Windows 10 settings.

To do this:

Open All Settings, and then go to Devices.

One the left-hand side of the Devices screen, select Typing and then scroll on the right-hand side until you locate Automatically show the touch keyboard in the windowed apps when there's no keyboard attached to your device

Turn this option to "ON"

Comment: sorry this does not work for me, i want to display the touch keyboard when i click on a text field in access

Comment: This works , for all the text fields. Did you try it ?

Comment: Anyway , what version of Windows do you have installed ?

Comment: i try, did the same steps as above, win version : Microsoft Windows 10 Pro, 10.0.14393 Build 14393

Comment: you have anoher example for vba in access in the top of answer

Comment: hm strange, this option is not listet in my settings, i look again after the update finished. thanks sir.

Comment: i dont mean osk.exe, its not the same as the one in my screenshot

Comment: i understand .... but it's no other ways as i know ... Try the windows 10 option , if you find it helpfull or it solve your question please upvote or mark as answer

Comment: i also find nothing on the net, but thats the reason why i ask here :D

Comment: i see ... :D :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Private Sub RunOsk_on64Bit()
Const SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1
    On Error Resume Next
    call ShellExecute(0, "open", "C:\windows\system32\osk.exe", "", "", SW_SHOWNORMAL)
End Sub
```